# Powershell New-Object : A constructor was not found

Tags: xml, powershell

I`m trying to create a function to get de NameSpaceManager, but i'm get a message error and a don't understand why.

```
 function Get-XmlNamespaceManager([ xml ]$xml, [string]$NamespaceURI = "")
{

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) { $NamespaceURI = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI            }


[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
return ,$xmlNsManager
```

}

Following the message:

```
New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type   System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager.
At C:\Scripts\Add Archive Handle\Add_Archive_Handle.ps1:35 char:53
+ ... NsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable) ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

But My $xmlNsManager returns:

```
PS C:\Path\To\Myfiles> $xmlNsManager
```

xmlns
xml
ns

Thanks for an help.

This is part of my code:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Scripts\Add Archive Handle\Source\' -Recurse -Include "*.imdi" -File | ForEach-Object {


 $NodePath = $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Resources.MediaFile.ResourceLink,$xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Session.Resources.WrittenResource.ResourceLink


 [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName; 
 $xml= $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.OuterXml;
 $xmlAtt = $xml.CreateAttribute("ArchiveHandle")
 $dt = $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Attributes.GetNamedItem('Date')
 $xmlAtt = $xml.METATRANSCRIPT.Attributes.InsertBefore($xmlAtt, $dt);



   function Get-XmlNamespaceManager([ xml ]$xml, [string]$NamespaceURI =""){

  if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) { $NamespaceURI = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI }
[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager =New-Object  System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
return ,$xmlNsManager }

   function Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath([string]$NodePath, [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.'){
   return "/ns:$($NodePath.Replace($($NodeSeparatorCharacter), '/ns:'))"}

   function Get-XmlNode([ xml ]$xml, [string]$NodePath, [string]$NamespaceURI = "", [string]$NodeSeparatorCharacter = '.'){
$xmlNsManager = Get-XmlNamespaceManager -XmlDocument $xml -NamespaceURI  $NamespaceURI
[string]$fullyQualifiedNodePath = Get-FullyQualifiedXmlNodePath -NodePath $NodePath -NodeSeparatorCharacter $NodeSeparatorCharacter  
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode($fullyQualifiedNodePath, $xmlNsManager)
return $node}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
                                         "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
```

That is the location for the specific error. There isn't an error with this specifically, but it only became an error because of how you called the function.

```
$xmlNsManager
```

As you probably know (since you made the function I presume) the function takes two parameters, (`$xml` and `$namespaceuri`). `$namespaceuri` can be `null` and is not mandatory, however though you haven't specified that `$xml` is mandatory, it is since of the things you have to do with it. (

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) {$NamespaceURI = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI}
#                                                          here ^
[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
#                                                                                   and here^
```

)

If i run the function but I put the `$xml` parameter like so:

```
Get-XmlNamespaceManager -xml @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Identity PUBLIC "point.dtd" "point.dtd"[]>
<Identity  created="1525465321820" name="Onboarding - GUI - External">
  <Attributes>
    <Map>
      <entry key="displayName" value="Onboarding - GUI " />
      <entry key="firstname" value="Z Orphaned ID" />
    </Map>
  </Attributes>
</Identity>
"@
```

I don't get an error, instead I get the output:

```
xmlns
xml
ns
```

I don't know if this is your intended output, but the error is caused because of the empty parameters. To guarantee that `$xml` is required, you can do:

```
function Get-XmlNamespaceManager([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][xml]$xml, [string]$NamespaceURI = "")
{
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($NamespaceURI)) {$NamespaceURI = $xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI}

[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]$xmlNsManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$xmlNsManager.AddNamespace("ns", $NamespaceURI)
return ,$xmlNsManager   
}
```

So now if I do

```
Get-XmlNamespaceManager
```

It will ask me for parameters

```
cmdlet Get-XmlNamespaceManager at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
xml:
```

And if I don't enter the parameters there by pressing `enter`, this will pass `$xml` as `""`.

Comment: Hi Neko, Thanks for you help and explanation, you right that is my intended output, but without enter the xml value, on the pipeline. It will return the output and will be used in another function.

Comment: It will not *be used in another function* it is just that your function seems to always return the same thing .Try resetting the powershell scope with a new window or the `powershell` command and run the function again. It will be the same.

Comment: All variables defined in a function without `$global:` will not change in the environment outside of it. Example, create function `function myfunc{$test = "test"}` and run it and see if `$test` is usable outside of the function then try using `function myfunc{$global:test = "test"}` and see if you can use `$test` outside of teh function then.